# Not able to fetch data from JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have json File.
By using Ajax call,i am trying to fetch data from Json File.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#day" ).click(function() {
        var actualDate = new Date(); // convert to actual date
        var date=actualDate.getDate();
        var month=actualDate.getMonth() +1;
        var year= actualDate.getFullYear();
        var today=date+"-"+month+"-"+year;
        alert(today);

        startJsonSession();
        return false;
    });

    function  startJsonSession(){
        alert("Am IN startJsonSession Method!!!!");

        $.ajax({
            url: "text.json",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                    alert(index + ': ' + value.Date);
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And Json File is :

```
[
    {
        "Date": "04/08/2014",
        "EventName": "Metting",
        "EventDescription": "abcfdggf",
        "Image": ""
    },
    {
        "Date": "04/08/2014",
        "EventName": "Public Meeting",
        "EventDescription": "xyz",
        "Image": ""
    }
]
```

Can You Please Suggest Me..

Comment: What is your problem? Please be specific. As it is, I have no idea what's not working.

Comment: I have added jquery-1.10.2.js also,but still it is showing Cannot read property 'length' of undefined . i want retrieve the value of Date key.but unfortunately not getting.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` is script error, code below that wont execute, are you using length property in your javascript

Comment: Ive written a localised version of this... http://jsfiddle.net/6vbYy/ and your "success" function should work if indeed it is brinign back the data... I would suggest there is other JS that is attempting to use a length property that is causing an error.

Comment: No I am not using any length property in this script..@super

Comment: I tried this one,it is working fine,when i acces through Ajax call,it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use **getJSON** this  is working with ur json file i have tested

```
$.getJSON('text.json', function (data) {

                 $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                console.log(val.EventName );
                });

            });
```

Comment: Suppose one Calendar is there.If i click on Particular date,it will show that date events.And that events will come from Json File.that Previous example is For today.Today is 5th August.if i click 5th,it will show and if i click on 4th August also it has to show 4th date Events.So how it will be..Can U please Suggest Me.

Comment: Xterm Sorry Man i dont have that Much reputation for vote.Just now i have created account...@ Liitle